# How to display a box drawing character using the ncurses crate?

Tags: rust, ncurses

I'm writing an app using Rust and ncurses.

I'm trying to display a box drawing character ('┃' (Unicode 9475 / 0x2503)), but it's as if it's not even printed to screen. When I select the text, it can be seen:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's a minimal example:

```
use ncurses::*;

fn populate_line_numbers() {
    for i in 0..LINES() {
        mvaddstr(i, 0, &i.to_string());
    }
    mvvline(0, 4, 9475, LINES());
    refresh();
}

fn main() {
    setlocale(LcCategory::all, "");
    initscr();
    start_color();
    keypad(stdscr(), true);
    noecho();
    loop {
        let user_input = get_wch();
        match user_input.unwrap() {
            WchResult::Char(ch) => {
                match ch {
                    27 => break,
                    _ => {
                        addstr(&std::char::from_u32(ch).unwrap().to_string());
                        refresh();
                    }
                }
            },
            WchResult::KeyCode(code) => {
                match code {
                    KEY_F5 => {
                        populate_line_numbers();
                    },
                    _ => {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    endwin();
}
```

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to make the program show line numbers.

How can the character be like the normal text? I tried to OR it together with a bunch of things, but nothing worked out.

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
ncurses = { version = "5.99.0", features = ["wide"] }
```

Comment: So where are you trying to display it? Maybe you should be using [`ncursesw`](https://docs.rs/ncursesw/0.5.1/ncursesw/) @edit `x=4`? There is no variable `x` in your code.? I guess you do that at `addstr`, I guess `addstr(...)` -> `addwstr(ch)`

Comment: @KamilCuk It should be displayed at `x=4`.

Comment: @KamilCuk What I meant is, `mvvline(0, 4, 9475, LINES());` where 4 is the x coordinate.

Comment: Och, and that "9475" magic number is supposed to be ┃? Can't you just `mvvline(0, 4, '┃', LINES());`  [The character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2503) in UTF-8 is composed of 3 bytes. The magic 9475 seems like html character encoding, no, rust doesn't encode characters using html escapes, rust uses utf-8

Comment: @KamilCuk No, mvwvline wants a u32.

Comment: Looks like the line is drawn in black on black. How do you tell it which colour to draw?

Answer (score 1):

> **Author's note:** The following is a best-effort analysis based mostly on examining ncurses.h on my system and comparing it to the source code of [ncurses-rs](https://rust.godbolt.org/). I may be wrong in some particulars.

In ncurses, the `chtype` type alias (which is the third argument of `mvvline`) represents a single-byte character plus some appearance metadata. It cannot store a multibyte character. So `mvvline` simply cannot display `┃`.

(Presumably the reason you get an invisible line is because the value `9475` represents a control character with some bogus appearance information. I wasn't able to figure out how to decode it. If you fiddle around with the byte values I'm sure you can get the line to change colors and contain any ASCII character you want.)

To draw a line using a "wide" (multibyte) character, you must link to a version of ncurses with wide character support, and use the wide character version of `mvvline`, which appears to be called [`mvvline_set`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mvhline_set). This function takes a `const cchar_t *` argument instead of `chtype`, where `cchar_t` is a struct containing a multibyte character plus some metadata.

Unfortunately, although the ncurses crate does link to the correct version of the ncurses library, it does not expose any way to call `mvvline_set`. There are a number of other functions that are also missing from the ncurses-rs API, mostly the ones that use the `cchar_t` struct. This means you won't be able to use Unicode line-drawing characters in character-oriented ncurses functions, unless you write the bindings yourself.

You should still be able to use multibyte characters in UTF-8 strings and pass them to string-oriented functions such as `mvaddstr`.

Comment: `9475` is 0x2503 (which happens to give 0x25 color pair, and the low-order 8-bits is the actual character).